# Add constraint based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `Phone` that has two columns `Number varchar(32)` and `Extension varchar(32)`. I'd like to add a `Constraint` with the following criteria:

1. Phone number is required if extension is not provided.
2. Extension is required if phone number is not provided.
3. Both phone number and extension can be provided.

I added the following `Constraint` to meet all three requirements:

```
ALTER TABLE Phone
ADD CONSTRAINT RequirePhone
CHECK (
    Number IS NULL AND EXTENSION IS NOT NULL
    OR (Number IS NOT NULL AND Extension IS NULL)
);
```

The above `constraint` meets the first two requirements, however, if I provide `Number` and `Extension` I get constraint exception.

I have tried adding:

```
...
OR (Number IS NULL AND Extension IS NULL)
```

But I still get the same error.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't your last clause has to be

```
OR (Number is NOT NULL AND Extension IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Yes - with this instead of IS NULL, you can insert either, both but you cannot insert NULL, NULL.

Comment: That's what I was about to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(1)..(3) is equivalent to *both NULLs is forbideen all the rest is OK*.

```
ALTER TABLE Phone
ADD CONSTRAINT RequirePhone
   CHECK (Number IS NOT NULL OR Extension IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Comment: Serg's answer should be the correct (yet concise) one.